# What is difference between Promo Graphics and Feature Graphics in Play Store

Tags: android, graphics, google-play

I am going to design the **Promo Graphics** and **Feature Graphics**. I tried to search what is **Promo Graphics** and **Feature Graphics**. I get where does the feature graphics will come and what it is, But I cant get what Promo Graphics means and where does it comes in play store. Can anyone show what it is and where it will come on play store.

Comment: I'm using this tool to generate  [android feature graphics](http://uncaughterror.com/Android-Feature-Graphic-Generator.php?ref=so)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Promo graphics** is promotional graphics, popular featured apps with high ratings get to display the promotional graphic.

Selected applications which are trending or most downloaded or chosen by editor in their respective categories get their promo graphics visible at the top. This is not guaranteed, but uploading promotional graphics is something which is recommended all the time, as you never know when your app tops the list.

> NOTE: The promo text has turned into a short description and is now
> shown on the main info page, before the user presses it to view the
> full description.
> Not all of the promotional assets are required, but all are
> recommended so that your app can participate fully in the Android™
> Market.

At the same time, the **Feature Graphic** is used for promotions on Google Play. Graphic is required to save and publish your Store Listing, it is required in order to be featured on Google Play.

To restrict the promotion of your app across Google-owned properties, you can check the "Marketing opt-out" tick box on your app's **Pricing & Distribution** page.

[image: Example of promo image in android play store]

Comment: "At the same time, the Feature Graphic is used for promotions on Google Play. While this graphic is not required" This is NOT correct, as of now you cannot publish/update apps if the Feature Graphic is not set.

Comment: You are right @kai, Feature graphic is made mandatory now. Thnx for the correction

Comment: @ Akshay, Do you have any screenshot on Promo Graphics to share here.

Comment: And also while seeing on this link https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1078870?hl=en , It seems promo graphics is used for Older version applications. But your answer seems to be different. Can you clarify it.

Comment: The Promo Graphic is used for promotions on older versions of the Android OS (earlier than 4.0). This image is not required to save and publish your Store Listing. While Google may use this anywhere, these seem to be used in the most recent versions of the Market app when apps are shown as tiles. Although this is optional, it's highly recommended. The graphic should not contain borders strictly.

Comment: Added supporting image.

Comment: Is that the Promo Graphics. I think it is Icons for the applications

Comment: Thats promo graphics @MohammedHussain

Answer (score 6):

update one point: The promo graphic is not needed anymore, except for users still using earlier than Android 4.0

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1078870?hl=en

*The promo graphic is used for promotions on older versions of the Android OS (earlier than 4.0). This image is not required to submit an update for your Store Listing.*

Answer (score 0):

Although it is required, I have never seen a promo-graphic for any of my apps being used for PC or android browsers, or Play Store. Perhaps it is a graphic that fits into ads, just a guess due to the size requirements.

All I know is:

- file MUST be 180px x 120px
- file MUST be .PNG format
- file MUST be uploaded in order to publish your app as of August 2020